# connection not secure - after deploying my react app on netlify and adding a custom domain

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, dns, netlify

I have a deployed my application on netlify with a custom domain.

My domain was on Hostinger, I have already given the DNS control to the netlify, and added the domain as specified on the netlify.

[image]

On some devices I am not able to open my website link using custom domain, here are the error messages displayed on Chrome and Firefox respectively.
Showing connection to this site is not secure even tough I have HTTPS enabled.

[image]

[image]

On some devices I am able to open the website link and it works fine with HTTPS enabled.

Do I need to buy a SSL certificate for this issue to be resolved?